# ggplot2 custom colour based on factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, match

Hello stackoverflow community,

I would love to get some ideas to improve my existing plot.

So I have a correlation dataframe in long format which roughly looks as follows:

[image]

and my idea was to make a factor of A since I have fewer As and they correlate with many Bs and plot the correlation value for each A with B using the following code. however, in the B column some labels exactly match with A

I was wondering if anyone of you could give me ideas on how could this be possible, to just colour the elements in B which exactly match with elements in A.

Best,

> `ggplot(df, aes(x=B, y=correlation_value)) +  geom_point() +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),text=element_text(size=8))+ facet_wrap( ~ factor(df$A))`

The code runs fine but I want to improve it further by adding custom colour. However, this colour should only be for points in B whose names match with A

Comment: You could first add a column that checks if the number in `A` is equal to the number (or value) in `B`, then use `color=<new_column>` in `aes`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  this was the most simple solution :)